# What's the best way to deal with multiple QT Designer UI files in one program?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer

Hi I have a program that uses multiple QT Designer UI forms.  When I add the second form (the main window form) to the project by simply adding the UI file I can no longer build or run the project.  What's the best way to deal with this situation?  One of the forms is an introductory wizard to guide the user through some steps.  When the wizard is complete I would like to show another form - the main window form.  These two forms are contained in separate files.  The project runs fine with one UI file but when I add the second is when the trouble starts.  It looks like my project defaulted to using the pointer variable single inheritance approach as described [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html).  Thanks!

Comment: How did you add your second UI? did you use *Add New. . .* -> *Qt Designer Form* or *Add New. . .* -> *Qt Designer Form Class*??

Comment: Form without class

Answer (score 1):

you should add a *Qt Designer Form Class*. use the .ui form file to design your UI, and use the C++ class to code the logic. This way, when you want to your UI to show up, just create an object of the class and call `.show()` on it (the same way `MainWindow` works). . .

Comment: Thanks for the help.  What was confusing me was the first UI file required no UI form class so I was hoping I could do the same with my other forms.  Sounds like this isn't possible right?

Comment: @JoshOrenberg, the first UI **does** have a form class (called `MainWindow`) , it is declared in `mainwindow.h` and implemented in `mainwindow.cpp`

Comment: @JoshOrenberg, and it is used in `main.cpp` where the class is instantiated. . .

Comment: Ugh more problems... I created a .ui file in the standalone QT Designer but can't find a way to add the ui file to the existing project as a qt designer form class in Qt Creator.  When I add the ui file alone to the project I get the same results as originally where I can't build the project.  So how to add the lone ui file to my project?  Same situation - a wizard followed by a main screen.

Comment: Solved the problem.  What I did was File --> New File or Project -> QT Designer Form Class -> what template you want -> name your class -> make sure to add to the existing project in the next screen -> if you already have a .ui file it will ask if you want to overwrite it.  I chose to overwrite but the original was preserved for whatever reason - make sure to back up your form just in case.

Comment: I successfully created the new class + ui.  What is the best way to communicate with the new ui class's members?  I need to get information from the original wizard ui (some checkboxes) and display qlabels for each of the checked boxes in the new main screen ui.  When I try to access the components of the new main screen ui from my main program c++ file I cannot access the main screen ui components.

Comment: you can define public functions in your Form's class to set those labels, and just call them before calling `.show()` when you use your class in the main window.

Comment: one more thing - I had to rename the parent Widget in QT Designer to the same name as the form class, case sensitive.  In case anyone reading this has trouble